# In real_time_pose_estimation no errors but fails to detect the object

Tags: c++, opencv, pose-estimation

I am working on real time pose estimation and you can find the code here
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/real_time_pose_estimation (samples given in opencv 3.1.0).

It has two stages:

1. model registration(Registering the 3D textured model of the object to be detected in a .yml file)
2. model detection

   - if I send the .yml file(cookies_ORB.yml)  which is already there in /real_time_pose_estimation/Data then detection is successful as expected
   - why its not detecting if I manually register the 3D textured model of the object in .yml file and ending with unexpected output .

This is what I do:

[image: Keypoints]

[image: create my own textured 3D model:]

error [image: model detection]

expected output-

[image: successfully detecting if I use cookies_ORB.yml file input]

Comment: I edited your question for it to be clearer. Kindly read [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Comment: Thank you J.chomel